# Arduino development with embedXcode in Xcode

Tags: xcode, arduino, codesense, arduino-ide

I've been recently using embedXcode for some Arduino related projects. Those who are familiar to Arduino knows that [code sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelli-sense) is not an option you can get in the Arduino IDE. That's why embedXcode gives you the freedom to get the code sense of [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) along with the other functionalities in Arduino IDE.

Now the problem I'm having is even though the standard C++ code are recognised by Xcode, it can't yet recognise the Arduino-specific codes. For example, in `void loop(){}`, `void` is highlighted but not `loop`. In the same way while typing pinMo... It's not showing any suggestions. As it was mentioned in the embedXcode tutorial, after running the automatic project configuration, the code sense should work. But I couldn't figure out any solution. Am I doing something wrong or is there any little tweak I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was posted in the Arduino forum by avenue33 which solved my problem. After commenting out the whole core library for code-sense section except `#include "Arduino.h"`, 
code sense works perfectly in Xcode using embedXcode.

Those who might be facing similar problems can try commenting out the core library section except `#include "Arduino.h"`.

Happy coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the updated release that addresses this issue.

embedXcode • Feb 08, 2014 release 131 • Improved indexing for code-sense

The `#include "Arduino.h"` statement is required.